A French movie about a mother searching her missing kid
I'm looking for a French movie which was made in between 2001-2009 about a married couple loses their kid and the mother desperately searches her child. The movie starts with a family moving to their new house or new summer house. It was a house with a big garden and near to the forest in countryside. The area was less populated. I think it was in West or South France. 
The kid had no friends nor siblings and was always on his own. He was blonde and at the aged between 8 - 12. Just after they moved to the house he had gone missing. The family called the police and they searched the area for a while but they came out empty. The mother begged them to search more but they said they've done everything that they could. Her husband told her to lose hope from the kid but she denied it and continued searching on her own. 
While she's been searching she met a guy. I couldn't remember he was a police or not. He was black, tall and medium aged. During the search she lost her hope couple of times. I remember a scene that she was sitting in an empty bath tub and crying. The man keep saying that 'don't cry , we'll find him'. And another scene that they were checking a trunk of an empty car near to the seaside. 
I couldn't remember if they find the kid or not but it's possible that to this was connected with her husband and his business associates. 
The mother was white, blonde, kinda tall, in her late 30s. Her husband was white, in his late 40s or early 50s, had grey hair and medium sized. 
The name of the movie could be 'The women in shadow' or something like that.  

Please try to come to grips with how punctuation works in written English language. The repairs people made to your questions should already give you an overview of how whitespace works around punctuation and make for a good learning example from which future questions can surely profit.

After an extensive search I found it. It is called La femme de l'ombre or 'Women of the shadow' in English . It's a 110 mins and 2003 made French drama movie. Unfortunately I couldn't find a trailer neither. 

Holiday Carole and Simon Vasseur turn to nightmares when their little seven year old daughter is kidnapped in the parking lot of a hospital. Very soon suspected by the police, Carole is arrested and detained before being released through the story of a witness who died shortly after in a suspicious accident. On his release from prison, her husband also disappeared and Carole undertakes research itself, in defiance of the law and the police persistent doubts. She realizes that she has been victim of a conspiracy and his own secret, she thought well kept for seven years, is behind the kidnapping of his daughter.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.

And please try to come to grips with how punctuation works in written English language. The repairs people made to your questions should already give you an overview of how whitespace works around punctuation and make for a good learning example from which future questions can surely profit.

@Napoleon Wilson I found some french pages and translated to english . Also i remember the cast by the pohotos . Sadly there's not any english references about ithe movie . Here's the french link ; http://www.cinemotions.com/La-Femme-de-l-ombre-tt20965

@michael link say it's a TV show not film http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1780701/?ref_=tt_ov_inf

Feel free to add [edit] any relevant details into the answer.

@AnkitSharma There're lots of mistakes on the imdb page so i deleted it. The details on the French page is correct so i translated to English and put a poster.
